# Confusion on Compact Space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**Definition.** If for any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$, there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal V$ of $\mathcal U$, we call $X$ is compact.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $X$ be compact. If $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is the decreasing nonempty closed sets in $X$, $\cap_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n\not=\emptyset$.
>
> The theorem is direct to prove, and if we substitute total ordered set for $\mathbb N$, we can also draw similar conclusion. My question is that after substitution, is the converse true?
>
> **Question 1.** For any total ordered set $\Lambda$, and $\{F_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is the decreasing nonempty closed sets in $X$, $\cap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F_n\not=\emptyset$ $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ is compact?
>
> ---
>
> **Theorem 2.** Let $X$ be compact set, and $A$ be an infinite set in $X$. Then $A$ has a limit point.
>
> **Question 2.** For any $A$ be an infinite set in $X$, $A$ has a limit point $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ is compact?

Could someone give some advice? Better with some examples. Thank you.

Comment: These should in fact be two different questions. If $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, then $X$ is limit point compact. This is equivalent to countable compactness if $X$ is a $T_1$-space and is equivalent to compactness if $X$ is a metric space. I believe that for question 2, $X$ is compact.

Comment: If indeed $X$ is compact, then the following proof holds: If no point of $X$ were a limit point of $A$, each $q\in X$ would have a neighborhood $\mathcal{V}_q$ which contains at most one point of $A$. No finite subcollection of $\{\mathcal{V}_q\}$ can cover $A$. This is true of $X$, since $A⊂X$, which contradicts the compactness of $X$.

Comment: for question 2, the minimal uncountable well-ordered set is a counterexample. for question 1, that is true because any set can have an order relation put on it and $X$ is compact iff for every collection of subsets with the finite intersection property, the intersection of all those subsets is nonempty.

Comment: @RRTT What is *minimal* uncountable well-ordered set? A concrete example is useful to me. Thank you.

Comment: @RRTT I'm disagree with your comments on question 2. I assume $\Lambda$ is total ordered set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

You actually get a stronger version of compactness from your stated principle:

> **(★)** Given a totally ordered set $\Lambda$ and $\{ F_\lambda \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a decreasing family of nonempty closed subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Lambda} F_\lambda \neq \varnothing$.

First, to see that (★) implies compactness, we prove by induction on the ordinal $\alpha > 0$ that if $\{ F_\xi : \xi < \alpha \}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property, then $\bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} F_\xi \neq \varnothing$.

- For $\alpha < \omega$ (finite ordinals), this follows because of the finite intersection property itself;
- Suppose the result is true for some $\alpha$, and let $\{ F_\xi : \xi < \alpha + 1\}$ be a family of closed sets with the f.i.p.  Then $\{ F_\alpha \cap F_\xi : \xi < \alpha \}$ is also a family of closed sets with the f.i.p., and so $\bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} ( F_\alpha \cap F_\xi ) = \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha + 1} F_\xi$ is nonempty by the induction hypothesis.
- If $\alpha > 0$ is a limit ordinal, and the result is true for all $\beta < \alpha$, then $E_\beta := \bigcap_{\xi < \beta} F_\xi$ is a nonempty closed set for all $\beta < \alpha$, and clearly $\beta < \gamma < \alpha$ implies $E_\gamma \subseteq E_\beta$.  It thus follows that $\bigcap_{\beta < \alpha} E_\beta \neq \varnothing$ (by property (★) of $X$), and it is easy to show that $\bigcap_{\beta < \alpha} E_\beta = \bigcap_{\beta < \alpha} F_\beta$.

So given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of closed subsets of $X$ with the f.i.p., if we enumerate it as $\{ F_\xi : \xi < \alpha \}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ it follows that $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = \bigcap_{\xi < \alpha} F_\xi \neq \varnothing$.  Therefore $X$ is compact.

But, as I said above, we get a stronger property from this property.  Consider the following definitions:

> **Definition:** By a *net* in a topological space $X$ we mean a function $f : \Sigma \to X$ where $\Sigma$ is any [directed set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).  We often denote nets by $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$.
>
> - A net $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$ is said to *converge* to $x \in X$ if for each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is a $\tau \in \Sigma$ such that $x_\sigma \in U$ for all $\sigma \in \Sigma$ with $\tau \leq \sigma$.
> - By a *subnet* of a net $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$ we mean a net of the form $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in T}$ where $T \subseteq \Sigma$; it is called *cofinal* if for each $\sigma \in \Sigma$ there is a $\tau \in T$ with $\sigma \leq \tau$.
> - A net $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$ is called *linearly ordered* if $\Sigma$ is a totally ordered set.
>
> **Definition.** A topological space $X$ is called *chain compact* if every linearly ordered net in $X$ has a convergent cofinal subnet.

I claim that every topological space satisfying your property (★) is actually chain compact.  Suppose that $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$ is a linearly ordered net in $X$.  For each $\sigma \in \Sigma$ define $F_\sigma = \overline{ \{ x_\tau : \tau \geq \sigma \} }$.  Clearly $\langle F_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in \Sigma}$ is a descending linearly ordered family of nonempty closed subsets of $X$, and so by (★) it follows that $\bigcap_{\sigma \in \Sigma} F_\sigma \neq \varnothing$.  Taking any $x \in \bigcap_{\sigma \in \Sigma} F_\sigma$, by properties of [Moore-Smith convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) it follows that there is a cofinal subnet $\langle x_\sigma \rangle_{\sigma \in T}$ which converges to $x$.

It should be noted that some very familiar compact spaces are not chain compact: one example is the closed unit interval $[0,1]$.  (If $\langle x_\xi \rangle_{\xi < \omega_1}$ is any one-to-one $\omega_1$-sequence in $[0,1]$, it follows that no *cofinal* subnet is convergent (there are convergent subnets, but these are not cofinal).)

**Question 2**

As mentioned in the comments, this is false.  The property you have given is called [*limit point compactness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact).  An in general stronger property called [*countable compactness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space) is equivalent to it in the realm of T<sub>1</sub> spaces. While every compact space is limit point compact, the converse does not hold.

The prototypical counterexample would be the [ordinal space $\omega_1 = [ 0 , \omega_1 )$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal).  If $A \subseteq [0 , \omega_1)$ is infinite, then we can  find a strictly increasing sequence $\langle \alpha_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A$.  It follows that $\alpha = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \alpha_n$ is itself a countable ordinal, and not too difficult to show that it is a limit point of $A$.  However $[ 0 , \omega_1 )$ is not compact: the family of open sets $[ 0 , \alpha )$ for $\alpha < \omega_1$ comprises an open cover with no finite (actually, no countable) subcover.

Comment: *familiar compact* $\Longrightarrow$ *chain compact*, I think.

Comment: If $\cap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F_{\lambda}=\emptyset$, then $\cup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}F_{\lambda}^{c}=X$. From compactness, we can assume $F_{\lambda_1}^{c}\cup\dots\cup F_{\lambda_n}^{c}=X$. From totalness, we can assume $F_{\lambda_1}^{c}=X$.

Comment: @gaoxinge: Actually not.  It is a theorem of Mrówka, Rajagopalan, and Soundararajan that a space is chain compact iff it is compact and scattered (meaning that every nonempty subset has an isolated point).  This implies that even $[0,1]$ is not chain compact (though it is clearly compact).